# Foundation.Abide validating via AJAX call

Tags: ajax, validation, asynchronous, zurb-foundation

I'm writing a validator that ensures that the email address on a registration form doesn't exist. The problem is that Abide validation functions expect you to return wether the field is valid or not, which won't be possible if the validation function needs to do something async like an AJAX call. I *could* mark that ajax call as `async: false`, but then the UI blocks while the call is made, and that isn't acceptable.

I can append an error message to the `parent` element ok, but how can I let Abide know that the form has become invalid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to listen if a specific boolean variable have been changed after your *ajax async call* then make what have to be done. You can also look at [socket.io](http://socket.io).